AWS Step Functions and API Gateway can't pass http headers like x-api-key
I am running into an issue that appears extremely solvable on the outside, but it really a world of hurt on the inside. I have a simple setup with a REST API invoking a step function in AWS. I need to pass both the body and one header, x-api-key, as input parameters to my state machine in step functions.
Part one of the issue is step functions uses StartExecution for the integration. This doesn't accept headers. See here for more info. Therefore, one would have to pass the header as part of the input body to the state machine.
Here are a few approaches, that should work, or at least could work, but don't.
At first, I tried a mapping function like this:
{
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX",
  "headers": {
    "apiKey": "$input.params('x-api-key')"
  },
  "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')).replaceAll("\\'","'")"
}

or this:
{
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX",
  "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')).replaceAll("\\'","'")",
  "apiKey": "$input.params('x-api-key')"
}

Both correctly grab the x-api-key and body of the call, confirmed in API Gateway logs, and properly transforms them. However, as mentioned above, because x-api-key is not in the input string, in Step Function's logs, it only sees the input string. To be explicitly clear, it doesn't only map the input string, it literally only receives the input string and doesn't even receive the header to properly map it.
Which leads to this potential solution:
#set($body = $input.json('$'))
#set($token = $input.params().header.get('x-api-token'))

{
    "input":"{\"token\":\"$util.escapeJavaScript($token).replaceAll("\\\\'","'")\",\"body\":$util.escapeJavaScript($body).replaceAll("\\\\'", "'")}",
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX"
}


This mapping template correctly passes the header as part of the input string. However, in API Gateway it results in a "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException" error. I have tried many variants of this mapping template. Probably close to two dozen. This includes variants like trying to pass and define the input string in different ways. Encoding with util.toJson and avoiding #set like below:
{
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX",
  "input": "$util.toJson({
    \"apiKey\": \"$input.params('x-api-key')\",
    \"body\": $input.json('$')
  })"
}

or this:
#set($apiKey = $input.params('x-api-key'))
#set($body = $input.json('$'))

#set($inputMap = {
  "apiKey": $apiKey,
  "body": $body
})

{
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX",
  "input": "$util.toJson($inputMap)"
}


Clearly either I am missing something. Or there is a capability here that doesn't exist.

I think you may have had it with this mapping, but it looks like you're missing the quotes from around the value of the body element in the json for "input":
#set($body = $input.json('$'))
#set($token = $input.params().header.get('x-api-token'))

{
    "input":"{\"token\":\"$util.escapeJavaScript($token).replaceAll("\\\\'","'")\",\"body\":$util.escapeJavaScript($body).replaceAll("\\\\'", "'")}",
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX"
}

should be:
#set($body = $input.json('$'))
#set($token = $input.params().header.get('x-api-token'))

{
    "input":"{\"token\":\"$util.escapeJavaScript($token).replaceAll("\\\\'","'")\",\"body\":\"$util.escapeJavaScript($body).replaceAll("\\\\'", "'")\"}",
  "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:XXX:stateMachine:XXX"
}

Having that wrong would yield the SerializationException you're reporting

Gave this a run and still got the same SerializationException. Thanks for the suggestion though, I really appreciate it!
